Poetry version solving is confusing
I'm getting quite confused with Poetry version solving and I have no idea why what I'm doing isn't working.
I have a project and I'm adding as a dependency another package from an internal company repository, but I'm constantly getting python version conflicts. Let's say the name of the package I'm trying to add is external-package, it has the following dependencies in its pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.10"
requests = "^2.28.2"
pandas = ">=1.5.0"
requests-toolbelt = "^1.0"  # "^0.10.1"
pyarrow = ">=16.1.0,<18"
polars = "^1.12.0"

My new project has the following:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = ">=1.5.0"
polars = "^1.12.0"
pyarrow = "<18.0.0"
seaborn = "^0.13.2"
matplotlib = "^3.9.2"
requests = "^2.28.2"

Based on this it would seem to me that these projects' Python requirements should overlap on 3.9.x, but this is what I get when I try to add the package:
The current project's supported Python range (>=3.8,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - external-package requires Python >=3.9,<3.10, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.8,<3.9 || >=3.10,<4.0

Because no versions of external-package match >0.1.24,<0.2.0
 and external-package (0.1.24) requires Python >=3.9,<3.10, external-package is forbidden.
So, because mhi-tools depends on external-package (^0.1.24), version solving failed.

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties

    For external-package, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.9,<3.10"

The weird thing is that the actual python version in the external-package is the same as what's suggested by poetry, but this still doesn't work. Any idea what's going on here?

If your project depends on a package that requires Python 3.9, how can your project work on Python 3.8? Well, there are situations where it could, but this seems to be Poetry’s logic.

@Ry-, fair enough but even if I change my project to have python ^3.9, I still get exactly the same result.

Really, exactly? (Try >=3.9,<3.10.)

@Ry-, this worked, thanks!
